# PySerial Unable to Close on Read-Only Port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

We have a serial port configured to work one-way (read only), and a Python program that monitors what's being sent out from the device on that port. There's a different system that manages the device on a two-way serial port; this program just takes in data from its port and can't send anything over its port.

Everything in PySerial works fine. We use `serial_for_url` to create our serial object and are able to read from it repeatedly, and with no issues. However, when it comes time to close the serial object (whether from a direct call to `Serial.close()` or when the object is cleaned up on system shutdown), the Python process hangs. We've done some tracing to determine it's definitely the `close()` call that the process hangs on.

If we have this Python program connected on a normal two-way serial port, everything works fine, the call to `close()` completes, and everyone is happy. On a one-way connection, however, `close()` just doesn't work.

Is there some sort of workaround for this? It might be a little odd to have this configured one way, but it seems like `close()` must be trying some kind of output on the port that won't go through because of our setup. Short of attempting a special 'read-only' derivation of the `Serial` object, I'm not sure what to try. I've tried flushing the output/input buffers with the PySerial API and researched for a 'read-only' mode for PySerial or something similar, but have had no luck.

Comment: *"We've done some tracing to determine it's definitely the close() call that the process hangs on."* -- What (underlying) OS are you using?

Comment: Oops, I knew I'd forget something important. We're using Linux, Red Hat specifically.

Comment: Test if this issue could be all the way down in the UART driver: try using a different serial port, e.g. a USB adapter.